# Linker error while working with dynamic class loading in C++

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, linker, .so

I am trying to load a class dynamically into my code. In Polygon.hpp I have the class declaration and in triangle.cpp has the definition. I have generated triangle.so. 
I have included Polygon.hpp in my main.cpp. Also,I am trying to create a vector of polygon object but during vector.push_back linker is throwing "undefined reference" error. If I comment out the vector.push_back everything is working fine. I know I create a vector Polygon* and work with it but that is not possible in my case as this would lead to changes in the existing legacy code which sort of not desirable. 
Is there a way I could use this approach. 
here's the code:

Polygon.hpp

```
#ifndef POLYGON_HPP                                                          
#define POLYGON_HPP                                                          

class polygon {
protected:
    double side_length_;

public:
    polygon()
       : side_length_(0) {}

 virtual ~polygon(){}

 void set_side_length(double side_length) {
    side_length_ = side_length;
 }

 polygon (const polygon &obj);

 virtual double area();
};

// the types of the class factories                                          
typedef polygon* create_t();
typedef void destroy_t(polygon*);

#endif
```

triangle.cpp

```
#include "polygon.hpp"
#include <cmath>

double polygon::area() {
    return side_length_ * side_length_ * sqrt(3) / 2;
}

polygon::polygon(const polygon &obj)
{
    this->side_length_ = obj.side_length_;
}


// the class factories                                                             
extern "C" polygon* create() {
   return new polygon;
}

extern "C" void destroy(polygon* p) {
  delete p;
}
```

Compiling and generating .so:

```
g++ -fPIC -c traingle.cpp
g++ -shared -o traingle.so traingle.o
```

main.cpp

```
#include "polygon.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <dlfcn.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;

vector<polygon> t;   //creating a vector of polygon
// load the triangle library                                             
void* triangle = dlopen("./triangle.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (!triangle) {
    cerr << "Cannot load library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
    return 1;
}

// reset errors                                                          
dlerror();

// load the symbols                                                      
create_t* create_triangle = (create_t*) dlsym(triangle, "create");
const char* dlsym_error = dlerror();
if (dlsym_error) {
    cerr << "Cannot load symbol create: " << dlsym_error << '\n';
    return 1;
}

destroy_t* destroy_triangle = (destroy_t*) dlsym(triangle, "destroy");
dlsym_error = dlerror();
if (dlsym_error) {
    cerr << "Cannot load symbol destroy: " << dlsym_error << '\n';
    return 1;
}
// create an instance of the class                                       
polygon* poly = create_triangle();

t.push_back(*poly);  //---> this is where the linking error is happening
// use the class                                                         
poly->set_side_length(7);
    cout << "The area is: " << poly->area() << '\n';

// destroy the class                                                     
destroy_triangle(poly);

// unload the triangle library                                           
dlclose(triangle);
}
```

Compiling:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -ldl
/tmp/cc4RdzvX.o: In function `void   __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<polygon>::construct<polygon, polygon const&>(polygon*,  polygon const&)':
main.cpp: (.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorI7polygonE9constructIS1_JRKS1_EEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorI7polygonE9constructIS1_JRKS1_EEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x48): undefined reference to `polygon::polygon(polygon const&)'
/tmp/cc4RdzvX.o: In function `void std::_Construct<polygon, polygon&>(polygon*, polygon&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZSt10_ConstructI7polygonJRS0_EEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructI7polygonJRS0_EEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x44): undefined reference to `polygon::polygon(polygon const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please be more precise: `Polygon` and `polygon` are different, so is `triangle` and `traingle`

Comment: Guess you took your example from here: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/C++-dlopen It does work, so you have to check how and why your program is different.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Yes I took the example from there. But that example doesn't have vector and I m trying to make it work with vector.

Comment: The vector should contain only polygon-pointers, not polygons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `vector<polygon> t;` in `main.cpp`, which will make it to link against `polygon`'s ctor/dtor, that's the link error.

To resolve the issue:

1. Either follow @robert's answer to directly link `polygon.cpp`
2. Or avoid use the complete type of `polygon` in your `main.cpp`.

So you should define `vector<polygon*> t;` instead, and push/pop `polygon*` to/from the vector.

And you should not forget to call `destroy_triangle()` when you pop from the vector, otherwise you have memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Compile the `triangle.cpp`too: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp triangle.cpp -ldl`.
Or if you want to use the shared lybrary add `-ltriangle` to your command.

Comment: that would defeat the purpose of shared library ..ryt? Let say I only have polygon.hpp and triangle.so then ur suggestion may not work. I wanna load triangle.so during runtime.

Comment: Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out` at runtime, this way telling where it finds the library. Or copy it to a default location, where it is searched by default.